# Difference between (null) and <null>

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, null

When serialising JSON I have two types of null: `(null)` and `<null>` as the value of a `NSDictionary`.

What is difference and how to I validate against each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these are descriptions as printed by `NSLog()`, then `(null)` is a `nil` or `NULL` pointer, possibly the result of calling `objectForKey:` on a dictionary for an undefined key. In contrast, `<null>` is an instance of `NSNull`; possibly a placeholder thrown in by the JSON parser to signal a `null` value in the original JSON.

You can test for `nil` and `NULL` by comparing the object with a null pointer (or simply by using them in a context where a logical expression is expected):

```
if ([dict objectForKey:@"NonExistentKey"] != nil) {
    // yay, existent!
}
```

However, `NSNull` is a proper Objective-C class, so its instances are to be compared by the `isEqual:` message:

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"KeyOfWhichValueIsNull"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    // `null` in the JSON, but NOT `nil` or `NULL` at runtime!
}
```

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks. It's just a matter of trying it once, then you will know the difference forever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trouble is the dictionary key can be both `<null>` or `(null)`. I've added `if (![[self objectForKey:@"TheKEY"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [self objectForKey:@"TheKEY"] != nil)` and falls over at the first `<null>`.

Comment: `NSNull` is documented to be a singleton, so you can even compare it with `==`.

Comment: @MartinR You can, but that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @daidai, you want to use a logical "and" (`&&`) not "or". You're apparently trying to determine if there's a non-JSON-null object. You want it to both be not equal to `[NSNull null]` *and* not `nil`.